# Match group of variables and values with the nearest datetime

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a `transaction` table that looks like that:

```
transaction_start    store_no    item_no    amount    post_voided
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        101        45         N
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        105        25         N
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        109        40         N
2021-03-01 10:05:00       002        103        35         N
2021-03-01 10:05:00       002        135        20         N
2021-03-01 10:08:00       001        140        2          N
2021-03-01 10:11:00       001        101       -45         Y
2021-03-01 10:11:00       001        105       -25         Y
2021-03-01 10:11:00       001        109       -40         Y
```

The table does not have an id column; the `transaction_start` for a given `store_no` will never be the same.

Whenever a transaction is post voided, the transaction is then repeated with the same `store_no`, `item_no` but with a negative/minus `amount` and an equal or higher `transaction_start`. Also, the column `post_voided` is then equal to 'Y'.

In the example above, the rows 1-3 have the same `transaction_start` and `store_no`, thus belonging to the same receipt, containing three different items (101, 105, 109). The same logic is applied to the other rows: rows 4-5 belong to a same receipt, and so on. In the example, 4 different receipts can be seen. The last receipt, given by the last three rows, is a post voided of the first receipt (rows 1-3).

What I want to do is to change the `transaction_start` for the `post_voided` = 'Y' transactions (in my example, only one receipt - represented by the last three rows - has it) to the next/closest datetime of a similar receipt that has the variables `store_no`, `item_no` and (negative) `amount` (but `post_voided` = 'N') (in my example, the similar ticket is given by the first three rows - `store_no`, all `item_no` and (positive) `amount` match). The `transaction_start` for the post voided receipt is always equal or higher than the "original" receipt.

Desired output:

```
transaction_start    store_no    item_no    amount    post_voided
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        101        45         N
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        105        25         N
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        109        40         N
2021-03-01 10:05:00       002        103        35         N
2021-03-01 10:05:00       002        135        20         N
2021-03-01 10:08:00       001        140        2          N
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        101       -45         Y
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        105       -25         Y
2021-03-01 10:00:00       001        109       -40         Y
```

Here a link of the table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26142fa24e46acb4213b96c86f4eb94b

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is not clear what is "nearest datetime" - so, having example of input in your question - what is expected output? - please add to your question!

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant thank you for your response! I have added the desired output and changed the text. Let me know if it is clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select a.* replace(ifnull(b.transaction_start, a.transaction_start) as transaction_start)
from `project.dataset.table` a 
left join (
  select * replace(-amount as amount)
  from `project.dataset.table`
  where post_voided = 'N'
) b
using (store_no, item_no)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Consider below for new / extended example (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91f9f180fd672e7c357aa48d18ced5fd)

```
select x.* replace(ifnull(y.original_transaction_start, x.transaction_start) as transaction_start)
from `project.dataset.table` x 
left join (
  select b.transaction_start, b.store_no, b.item_no, b.amount amount, 
    max(a.transaction_start) original_transaction_start
  from `project.dataset.table` a 
  join `project.dataset.table` b
  on a.store_no = b.store_no
  and a.item_no = b.item_no
  and a.amount = -b.amount
  and a.post_voided = 'N'
  and b.post_voided = 'Y'
  and a.transaction_start < b.transaction_start
  group by b.transaction_start, b.store_no, b.item_no, b.amount
) y
using (store_no, item_no, amount, transaction_start)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you - it almost worked. When I have for example two transactions which are really similar - it is repeating both of them. To illustrate it, I have created a new example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91f9f180fd672e7c357aa48d18ced5fd
In this example, receipt 1 (rows 1-3), receipt 2 (rows 4-6) and receipt 3 (rows 7-9) are really similar. I would like to only match receipt 3, which has a transaction_start <= transaction_start from the post voided receipt. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks, it almost worked! The problem is when a transaction is "in-between" the original receipt and the post voided, this one is also duplicated. For the example, I have added the row ```transaction_start``` = '2021-03-01 10:04:00': https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06afe841d89c4ecbf600436433cd1c5d
This new receipt has ```item_no``` = 101 as the receipt transaction_start = '2021-03-01 10:00:00'. When I run your query, this one is also considered. But only the group of ```store_no```, ```item_no``` and ```amount``` should be considered, and not the individual ones. Thanks!

Comment: And sometimes the ```post_voided``` receipt has the exact same ```transaction_start``` from the original receipt. Can you change this part ```and a.transaction_start < b.transaction_start``` to ```and a.transaction_start <= b.transaction_start```? Thanks!

Comment: yes. obviously you can change `<` to `<=`. I fully answered your original and follow up question. the answers usually as good as questions are! so if you still have more nuances coming up - post new questions with new details - and I will be happy to help as always. Meantime - consider voting up and and  accept the answer

Comment: Regarding my last comment - you are right, not necessary. But regarding my second last comment, the query is not fully working yet. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks! :)

Comment: read my previous comment. your original question is fully answered. you tend to constantly adding new nuances to your case and this is not how SO works. rather you ask specific question and you got answer. if you realized that question was missing some nuances  - you should post new question - NEW. meantime, to respect time spent to answer your question - consider voting up etc. if you think i am wrong with this approach - no problem - hope someone else will jump in - good luck :o)

Comment: I have marked it as correct - but must say that I disagree with you. I have mentioned that it should be on a receipt level, not row level. But anyway, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: you don't need to accept answer if you think it does not fully answers your question. but voting up the answer that clearly helped you - is definitely something that you should do otherwise you are not motivating us to answer your questions. meantime, as I mentioned  - answers are as good as questions - so if you realized your question was missing some important (for you) details - be brave and stick with your original question, but post new one based on progress achieved with original one. Note: changing original question again and again is not welcome here on SO! :o)